# how to reset general purpose performance counter of intel

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, msr, intel-pmu

I know we can use `wrmsr` and `rdmsr`   instruction to set the performance counter and  read the general purpose performance counter register.

However, my question is:

Do we need to reset the general purpose performance counter register before we issue the `wrmsr`?

In other words, for the following code, do we need to reset the performance counter before the following code? If we have to, how can we reset it?

```
    mov $0x0001010E, %eax                # Write selector value to EAX
    xor %edx, %edx                       # Zero EDX
    mov $0x187, %ecx                     # Write logical register id to ECX (IA32_PERFEVTSEL1)
    wrmsr
```

Comment: You don't.  You simple record the current value.  Then sometime later you read it again and subtract the previous value.

Comment: Thank you very much, @HansPassant! Yes, your method is a way to do it. But I'm wondering if I can reset it? If both ways work, what's their strength and weakness?

Comment: you can use the (user level) rdtsc instruction. it requires no setup, just return sequential values (as mentioned, read first and subtract from later value). wrmsr and rdmsr are priviledged.

Comment: @AndreasH: `rdtsc` is useless if you want to measure (e.g) cache misses or branch mispredictions or unaligned reads or number of "non-bogus" uops retired on one logical CPU in a core but not the other, or...

Comment: @MikeXu: Which CPU is it? Performance monitoring counters on "Ye Olde Pentium" are very different to Haswell..

Comment: @Brendan, my cpu is  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz
 It uses the SandyBridge Arch.